# Search a column of values in a table and pull out their corresponding values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of values that I want to populate. I'd like to search them on a table and pull out their corresponding values:

[image]

So that I get the following names and their corresponding ages as they appear on the table.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E7`

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B14,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A14,E2:E5))),{2,1})
```

---

Alternative approaches:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H7`

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B14,MMULT(N(A2:A14=TOROW(E2:E5)),
SEQUENCE(ROWS(E2:E5),,,0))),{2,1})
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `K7`

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B14,COUNTIFS(E2:E5,A2:A14)=1),{2,1})
```

---